# Increase output current from LED Driver PCA9956B

Tags: led, driver

How can I increase the output current of LED driver IC [PCA9956B](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9956B.pdf)? I want to connect LED strips 1.5 A for each output 0-23 channels.

I considering power transistors N-Mosfet.

Comment: That's not going to be easy - your going to need a bunch of external circuitry to make that chip work the way you want it to work. So much so, that your going to be considering a complete architectural design change from the very beginning of attempting this.

Comment: It seems that the PCA9685 would be better as it has open-drain outputs. However, I need min. 20 channels. Unfortunately the PCA9685 only has 16 channels.

Comment: `need min. 20 channels […] the PCA9685 only has 16` making 2 PCA9685 look attractive?!

Comment: Yes, I can use 2x PCA9685 but will be better to use one PWM Controller with 24-channels and open-drain outputs. Does such a controller exist?